# Changing a value in one list changes the values in another list with a different memory ID

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been beating my head against a wall over this problem. I create a list and make 4 copies, only one of which shares the same memory index. If I change the original list, is somehow changes 3 of those copies as well, 2 of which have a different memory index. Only if I make a list using the same command as the original, am I able to create a list that is not impacted by changes to the original. How is this possible? Here is the output from my console:

```
>>> orig=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]
>>> id(orig)
151498220
>>> copy1=orig   #same index
>>> id(copy1)
151498220
>>> copy2=orig[:]   #different index
>>> id(copy2)
151498348
>>> copy3=list(orig)   #different index
>>> id(copy3)
151503020
>>> copy4=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]
>>> id(copy4)
151498636
>>> orig[0][1]=34
>>> copy1
[[0, 34, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]   #expected, same memory index
>>> copy2
[[0, 34, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]   #WTF?!?!?
>>> copy3
[[0, 34, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]   #ARGH!!!
>>> copy4
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]   #workaround?
>>> id(orig)
151498220
>>> id(copy1)
151498220
>>> id(copy2)
151498348
>>> id(copy3)
151503020
>>> id(copy4)
151498636
```

The memory indices did not change and yet the lists were altered. Only copy1 should have changed as it has the same memory index as orig.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you are just creating a shallow copy. You need to create a deep copy instead.

As per [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module doc:

> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>     the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

You can verify it by comparing the id of inner list:

```
>>> orig=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]
>>> id(orig)
151498220
>>> copy2=orig[:]   #different index
>>> id(copy2)
151498348

>>> id(copy2[0]) == id(orig[0])  # inner list have same id
True
```

You can create a `deepcopy` using [`copy.deepcopy(x)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
>>> import copy
>>> 
>>> copy3 = copy.deepcopy(orig)
>>> 
>>> id(copy3[0]) == id(orig[0])   # inner list have different id
False

>>> orig[0][3] = 34
>>> 
>>> orig
[[0, 34, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]
>>> copy3
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]]
```

Comment: Oh thank you thank you thank you! In all my searches, I could not find any documentation on this.

Comment: Done and done, is there a particular reason why copy1=list(orig) should not default to making a deepcopy? Is there a specific reason why you would want to retain the separate lists?

Comment: It would only affect if you modify the inner lists. Suppose you want to add new list inside the outer list, then `list(orig)` will also work. i.e, adding a newlist in the list returned by `list(orig)` will not add the list in the original list.

Comment: @AdrianReich: Generally, when you call `list` on something, you don't want copies of the elements. If `s` is a set of database connections, for example, you don't want `list(s)` to be a list of new, similar-looking database connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is a list of [*names*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables), not a list of lists as you are thinking of it.  When you make a copy of the list using any of the methods you list (slicing, creating a new list based on the old one, etc) you make a new outer list, but the names in the new list reference the same internal lists as the names in the old one.

```
# One through three are all examples of:

first_list, second_list, third_list = [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 123, 0]
original = [first_list, second_list, third_list]
another_list = original[:]

# We do indeed have another list
assert id(original) != id(another_list)

# But the *references* in the list are pointing at the same underlying child list
assert id(original[0]) == id(another_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because while the outer lists (`copy1`, `copy2`, etc.) are separate objects, their sublists are all references to the same lists you created in `orig`. Try doing:

```
id(orig[0]) == id(copy3[0]) #should return True
```

In order to make a deep copy of the list object *and* all the objects it references, use `deepcopy`.